# How can to show the row number in Nebula NatTable

Tags: eclipse-rcp, nattable, nebula

I can show a CSV content to a NatTable using those code:

```
IDataProvider bodyDataProvider = ...;

DataLayer bodyDataLayer = new DataLayer(bodyDataProvider);
SelectionLayer selectionLayer = new SelectionLayer(bodyDataLayer);
ViewportLayer viewportLayer = new ViewportLayer(selectionLayer);
viewportLayer.setRegionName(GridRegion.BODY);

natTable.setLayer(viewportLayer);
```

How can we show the row number? I tried to used `GridLayer` but there are no column header. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this. I used `CompositeLayer`:

```
IDataProvider rowHeaderDataProvider = new DefaultRowHeaderDataProvider(bodyDataProvider);
DataLayer rowHeaderDataLayer = new DataLayer(rowHeaderDataProvider);
ILayer rowHeaderLayer = new RowHeaderLayer(
                    rowHeaderDataLayer,
                    viewportLayer,
                    selectionLayer);
CompositeLayer compositeLayer = new CompositeLayer(2, 1);
compositeLayer.setChildLayer(GridRegion.ROW_HEADER, rowHeaderLayer, 0, 0);
compositeLayer.setChildLayer(GridRegion.BODY, viewportLayer, 1, 0);
natTable.setLayer(compositeLayer);
```